# CQRS - Assembly distribution

Tags: architecture, projects-and-solutions, cqrs

In a CQRS implementation should the Queries component be placed in a different assembly than the Commands component?

Example:

- SolutionA
- SolutionA.Query
- SolutionA.Command

Comment: My lawyer's favorite answer: It depends.

Answer (score 1):

It's about command query responsability SEGREGATION ^^

I think it's more preferable to seperate Command and Query (for clarity & SRP reason).

Query it's about repository responsability, command it's more domaine responsability.

You can take inspiration from [CQRS Journey](http://cqrsjourney.github.com/)